# Is idèle norm just a norm?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, adeles

$\def\fp{{\frak p}}\def\fP{{\frak P}} \def\bfm#1{{\mathbf#1}}\def\cE{{\cal E}}\def\fm{{\frak m}}\let\ss\subset $
I would like to make a link between idelic norm and "normal" norm.

For $L/F$ an extension of number field, one defines admissible module
$\fm$ by
$ \cE_\fm\ss N(\cE_L)$

(with $\cE_L=$  inversible ideles of
$L$ and $\cE_\fm$ inversible ideles of $K$ which are $=1\mod\fm$)

and i
would like to know if it is an idelic
version of the ideal one, generaly writen for the $\fp|\fm$. as $\bfm U_\fp^{(b)}\ss
N(\bfm U_\fP)$
where $\bfm U_\fp^{(b)}=1+\fp^b$, and for $\fP|\fp$, $\bfm U_\fP$ the units of $L_\fP$

My problem is that if $(\bfm a_\fp)$ is an idele of $K$ and $(\bfm
b_\fP)$ an idele of $L$, $\bfm a=N(\bfm b)$ means
$$a_\fp=\prod_{\fP|\fp}N(b_\fP)$$
and i would like to get rid of the product.

Is it possible ? Is it true ?
All this is of course around Artin map.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\fp{{\frak p}}\def\fP{{\frak P}}   $Hum !
I think i got it but i have some doubts.

Actually, $L_\fP=\tau L\,K_\fp$ for a $K$-imbedings $\tau$ into a closure of $K_\fp$. So two $L_\fP$ are isomorphe with a $K_\fp$ morphism so the pol. char. of the product by an element $x\in L_{\fP_1}$ is the same than the one for $\tau_2\circ\tau_1^{-1}(x)$ because the matrix invoques coefficients in $K_\fp$ and the base of $\tau L$ is just the image of a base of $L$ over $K$.

Consequently $N_{L_1}(x)=N_{L_2}(\tau_2\circ\tau_1^{-1}(x))$ with $L_i=L_{\fP_i}$

Am I right ?

So regarding my question all norms in the second member could be reduce to a norm in just one $L_i$.
I think i say something wrong, it's too simple, but i don't see where